# Lagrangian issue

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

I am working with a Lagrangian in the following form of dependence

$L(a,φ,m,a',φ')$ where the $a'$ means time derivative of $a$, $φ'$ the time derivative of $φ$ and $a(t)$, $φ(t)$, $m(t)$, $t$ is time.

This Lagrangian does not contain any time derivative of the $m$ component.So am I right to assume that the partial derivative of the Lagrangian with respect to $m$ is zero according to Euler-Lagrange equations?

Answer (score 1):

The Euler-Lagrange equation for $m$ reads:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial m'}\right)=\frac{\partial L}{\partial m} \tag{1},$$

if $\partial L/\partial m'=0$ then the LHS of the above is zero and therefore so is the RHS, so the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, just want to be  sure !!

Answer (score 1):

If the Lagrangian does not depend on $m'$, then by the Euler-Lagrange equations
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial m} \simeq \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial m'} = 0$$
where I use the symbol $\simeq$ to denote an equality *which holds for solutions of the equations of motion*. It of course does *not* mean that $\frac{\partial L}{\partial m}=0$ in general.

---

For example, consider the following Lagrangian:

$$L(x,x',y,y',m,m')=\frac{1}{2}(x'^2 + y'^2) + m(x^2+y^2-R^2)$$
where $R$ is some constant.  This Lagrangian has no dependence on $m'$. Note that $\frac{\partial L}{\partial m} = x^2+y^2-R^2$, which for arbitrary $x$ and $y$ is not zero; however, the equations of motion for the system are

$$x'' = 2mx$$
$$y'' = 2my$$
$$0 = x^2+y^2-R^2$$

The first two equations are second-order differential equations, but the third is just an algebraic relationship between the coordinates with no derivatives in it. This algebraic relationship constitutes a [constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier#Single_constraint) to which your system has been subjected, and the variable $m$ whose derivative does not appear in the Lagrangian is called a Lagrange multiplier.

In this particular case, the presence of a (non-dynamical) $m$ enforces the constraint that the position of the particle be restricted to the circle of radius $R$.  This is made more obvious by changing to polar coordinates, in which case the Lagrangian becomes

$$L(r,r',\theta,\theta',m,m')= \frac{1}{2}(r'^2 + r^2\theta'^2) + m(r^2-R^2)$$
and the equations of motion become
$$r'' = r\theta'^2 + 2mr$$
$$r^2\theta'' + 2r'\theta' = 0$$
$$0 = r^2 -R^2$$

The last equation implies that $r'=r''=0$, which means that $\theta''=0$ as well.  So the solution to the Euler-Lagrange equations is a particle moving with fixed radial coordinate $r=R$ and constant angular speed.